# Could Windows Update Computer Prevent Computer from Working With VGA Monitors? If not, then what? (And How Can I Fix?)

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, hdmi, vga, dvi

Sunday, my Windows 10 no-name machine received a large (5 hour) update.
Immediately after the update, the computer seemed to work.  However, I fell asleep listening to YouTube play music.

When I woke up, neither of the two monitors connected through a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti were displaying anything. One is an Acer V233H and the other is an Asus VS228. Both have a native resolution of Full HD (1080p) 1920 x 1080.  Both are connected to their respective VGA ports using adapters, one to the GeForce's HDMI port and one to the GeForce's DVI-D port.  I attempted to reboot the computer several times.  Nothing would display, not even pre-Windows stuff, like BIOS.

I tried to use the display ports on my motherboard, but (of course) they were disabled in the BIOS while the graphics card is plugged in, so I could not change the settings.  I tried to remove the graphics card, but it is jammed in the pretty well and I could not get it to release.  Not wanting to risk damaging either the card or the motherboard, I took the machine to a shop where behind closed doors they allegedly repaired it for €69.

When I arrived home, the machine seemed to behave exactly the same as before I went (no images on either monitor).  Exchanging some SMSs with the shop, I learned they tested only the DVI-D port (even though I told them to test all the ports); they suggested I should try a different monitor.

I don't have a different VGA monitor, but I do have two monitors which have both HDMI and DisplayPort.  I tried connecting these and discovered initially only the HDMI would work.  After I finally got into Windows, the DisplayPort also started to work.

I then tried to reconnect the original VGA monitors through their respective adapters.  The computer still won't communicate with either of them.  With the DVI-D adapter, the display will flicker on and off, but it won't be detected in Windows.  With the HDMI adapter, the display just remains completely inert.

I then tried hooking both of these monitors into a different computer (an HP laptop).  The monitors both work fine, as does the HDMI adapter (the laptop does not have any ports to test the DVI-D adapter).

Could the Windows update have done something which prevents the VGA monitors from working even before windows loads?

Regardless, is there anything I could do to fix this?

(VGA monitors may not be trendy, but it is ridiculous to waste them when they serve me perfectly well, present issue aside.)

Comment: Your question remains a bit unclear to me as VGA is 640x480 wheres 1920x1080 is not VGA.  Yes I would expect 1920 x 1080 to work. I deleted my answer because it was specific to VGA which does not appear to be the case here.

Comment: @john vga is also a connector: aka vga d-sub

Comment: There is the possibility that {magic} happened that prevents hdmi handshaking. Alternatively you were running on a previous driver that did not do handshaking and now it does (for e.g. content protection) and the adapter doesn't respond appropriately. This might explain why the adapter works on different hardware.

Comment: @Yorik, you might be onto something.  Can drivers effect functionality outside of Windows?  I would have thought that would require firmware.   Could/windows update that?  Whatever that is, is there any way to downgrade this safely?

Comment: "Could the Windows update have done something which prevents the VGA monitors from working even before windows loads?" - NO;  What you describe is not possible.  The **digital** protection other users are talking about are not even supported on VGA so it's impossible for those to be at fault.  *VGA is analog not digital*

Comment: @Ramhound, as I understand the other users, it is exactly because VGA does not support the digital protection, the HDMI handshake cannot be completed so the protection prevents the signal and therefore _could_ be at fault.  This thread describes a comparable issue: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/hdmi-to-vga-adpter-works-with-laptop-but-not-with-pc-please-help.3559811/

Comment: @BrianKessler - The author indicated their setup was working, I can't think of anything caused by a Windows Update (even if it was a display adapter driver update) that would cause the author's problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm the author.  I couldn't think of anything either.  So far the HDMI handshake theory seems the most likely thing I've heard, though I would have expected a change in behaviour that happens outside Windows would require a firmware update which I would not expect from an Windows update.

Comment: ... If I understand this correctly, maybe when Windows Update updates a driver, the driver in turn can update firmware:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/updating-device-firmware-using-windows-update

Comment: the only point I will say about handshaking is that the vga connector would be a red herring. Ramhound is of course correct about the lack of support, but *the adapter* is the part that would be handshaking. HDMI adapters and repeaters have exhibited this problem for a long time (poor design, licensing cost, and/or version issues). On top of that, there was a time I could not watch a DVD on my computer even with vga analog because the nvidia drivers locked out the functionality. That was a long time ago, though

Comment: @Yorik, not sure what you mean by "red herring" in this context.  I can't connect to the graphics card without it, so it is somewhat essential to the equation, though it is perhaps misleading in the sense that I expected the system to be agnostic about what is connected to the port.

Comment: I mean that *if*  it is due to something like handshaking, then anything downstream of the adapter is a distraction from the actual reason. It wouldn't matter *what* is connected to the adapter at that point.

Comment: Ah, I think it would be more accurate to say the VGA is the red herring as I was focused on it, not the adapter, but I take your meaning now.  :-)  Can you think of any way to prove your hypothesis without paying a fortune for more monitors to test with?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible?  Yes.  Is it likely... Probably not.  This sounds more like a driver issue than a Windows Update problem.  Perhaps Windows replaced your driver or changed the configuration.  I would start by downloading and installing the latest driver from nVidia and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: I've already tried updating my nVidia drives, without success.  I can contact nVidia's support and see whether they can give any advice towards downgrading....